# Soldiers keep falling on scuba tanks, what are common injuries?

Tags: medical

I've got some marines fighting on an alien planet, and the aliens have some weird kinetic weapon thing that is their main weapon. It basically throws the marines back. The best way I can think of describing it is if you put a board on a merry-go-round sticking out a few feet, get the merry-go-round going quickly, and then run into the board, that's probably what it feels like(I've never done that, but it's pretty close to what the alien weaponry does).

My main concern is that the marines each have a scuba tank on their back because they can't breathe the atmosphere, and when the aliens use their merry-go-blams on the marines, they tend to fall on it. I would imagine they would hit the back of their heads on the top of the tank, maybe on the pressure gauge, but then the bottom of the tank is right around the waist area, centered on their spine. What injuries would be common from falling on the tank?

Assume the tanks don't explode.

Comment: *"What injuries would be common from falling on the tank?"* You mean, what injuries would be common in the two or three days until the commander orders his men to use back protection? Even a thin plastic plank between the soldier's back and the tank would provide some protection, and within days some sort of jury-rigged cushion will be standard equipment. Marines are resourceful fellows.

Comment: This question seems very plot based. The injuries will simply be a function of the terminal motion of the marines' bodies -- some will be back injuries, some head injuries, some limb injuries, some facial injuries, probably some deaths as hoses are damaged or masks come undone. All in all, there is no worldbuilding problem or issue here, and that's the kind of question we deal with here.

Comment: They have air tanks, not scuba tanks.

Comment: @elemtilas Plot-based, how? This is about a feature of a world. Kinetic weapons knock down Marines wearing air-tanks, what injuries result? Anyone who thinks this is too story-based doesn't understand too story-based or how to write fiction.

Comment: @a4android - That's exactly why it's plot based. Whichever injuries you'd like to pick off the list are 100% valid. Also, don't assume what other people know or understand. I happen to understand what story based means, and why this is a matter of plot and not nature of a fictional world. I also understand how to write fiction and why writing questions should be asked in the writing forum. I also understand medical and relating motion to injury. None of that is "feature of a world".

Answer (score 8):

There are two impacts:

- when first pushed back, the body is accelerated faster than the tank, and impacts it.
- when landing, the tank is decelerated first, then the body hits it.

Each impact is the same body parts hitting the tank. But the tank is strapped to the body so there isnt too much force imparted. Having fallen over backwards with a scuba tank on my back before I give it 0 stars, and would not recommend. Passing boats wake rocked the boat and I still had flippers on. Left a mild bruise on my lower back. Pain was gone a few days later. I had a t shirt and wetsuit on, and there was strapping between the tank and my body.

A marine in a flak jacket or similar would have even more shielding than my wetsuit gave.

A much more violent impact will leave bigger bruises, and will definitely knock the wind out of them. Impacts of around 20gees and they wont be great at lifting heavy loads or running for a while, but I'd expect a professional fighter to be back on their feet in 10 seconds.

40gees and they'd be breaking bones with or without the tank.

Comment: Good on you for diving in to the forum, but please note that it's really not a good idea to [answer a query whose on-topicality is at question](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4968/please-dont-answer-and-or-upvote-bad-questions-yet) just yet. This forum exists to help people create fictional worlds. We deal with questions of *how* a fictional world works, not what might happen in a given narrative moment.