# Is there a site where I can simulate injuries or external events on humans?

Tags: worldbuilding-resources, medical, internet

As a sort of follow up to [this question](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/183885/soldiers-keep-falling-on-scuba-tanks-what-are-common-injuries), I'm looking for a (preferably free and no download needed) site that will let me simulate events on humans so I can get an accurate idea on how my characters should react.

In the immediate sense, I'm trying to answer said question, but if I can find a site like this I think it would really help with questions like 'what happens to my character when X happens?'. If you find something like this, please let me know.

*If it requires download or pay, it's not a deal breaker, so put it in an answer or comment anyways.*

Mutilate a Doll doesn't help.

Comment: I'd think that software that could replace crash-test dummies, ballistics testing, and who knows how many other cost-to-profit-critical product testing is likely to cost tens of thousands of dollars and require a small supercomputer to run. Anything you can find free and/or online will be a lot of work for minimal results. IMO.

Answer (score 4):

A package like Blender could give you some ability to simulate physics effects on bodies.  I doubt you'd be able to simulate the penetrating wound damage caused by a sword, but you ought to be able to simulate effects of explosions and collisions, including accounting for interactions with objects like tables and walls.

[image]

It would be a lot of effort, but its simpler, cheaper, than implementing your scenarios in a Finite Element Modeling tool.

Comment: Blender requires a download.

Comment: @DarePelletier,  yes, Blender needs to be downloaded and installed.  But, the poster sez that it is okay, not ideal, but it is okay.  So beyond a 'water is wet' sort of statement, is there some point to your observation.

Answer (score 1):

I hate paying and downloading too, but the best example I've seen is actually Euphoria Physics game engine:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c7fJGAK7EbQ

> The software allows characters and even players to perform enhanced animated movements more naturally and interactively by utilizing "on-the-fly" programming animation, combining artificial intelligence, biomechanics and physics. Euphoria covers nearly all in-game animated behaviors, including firearm usage, hand-to-hand combat, jumps and climbs, recoveries and interactions with in-world objects.

> In addition to enhanced animation cycles, Euphoria is also designed to perform more life-like animations and an underlying sense of self-preservation giving each character unprecedented interactivity and realism.

> For example, pedestrians who are knocked off-balance by a player will stumble around dynamically and grab onto objects (or other people) in the game world for support themselves. Characters who are falling, heavily injured, ejected from a car, etc. will also enter an "intelligent ragdoll" state -- rather than simply going limp -- which will cause them to protect their heads while rolling, reach out to break a fall with their hands, grab injured body parts and otherwise practice realistic self-preservation in a way that would be almost impossible to replicate with canned animation.

It's probably prohibitively expensive. I couldn't find a free demo. But is a decent simulation at what people do given external stimuli.

Maybe get GTA 5 (which uses the engine), get some cheet codes to structure the world how you want, and do your experiments in game?